# How to add a 2D array group which having reads from a file numbers in c?

Tags: arrays, c, file

I need to read a file which contain numbers, and make 4 rows and 5 columns matrices from those numbers. Then, I need to add these matrices and print the sum matrix (the numbers of matrices depends on the user input).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    int m;
    
    scanf("%d", &m);
    FILE *file = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
    
    int arr[a][b][m], i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            for (m = 0; k < m; k++) {  
                fscanf(file, "%d", &arr[i][j][k]);
                arr[i][j] += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                printf("%d", arr[i][j][k]);
                printf("\t");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @R_Dax I can't get the sum matrix!

Comment: `m=0 ; k<m; k++` oops.

Comment: @mehdi: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load the matrix data into separate matrices, you can just add the matrix contents on the fly as you read each matrix from the file:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m;
    
    if (scanf("%d", &m) != 1)
        return 1;

    const char *filename = "matrix.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    ]
    
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    int sum[a][b];

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                int value;
                if (fscanf(file, "%d", &value) != 1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "not enough data\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                sum[i][j] += value;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you are required to load all the data in memory, use an array of matrices: `int arr[m][a][b];` and 2 separate loops to read and sum the data:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m;
    
    if (scanf("%d", &m) != 1)
        return 1;

    const char *filename = "matrix.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    ]
    
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    int arr[m][a][b];

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                if (fscanf(file, "%d", &arr[k][i][j]) != 1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "not enough data\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    int sum[a][b];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            int s = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                s += arr[k][i][j];
            }
            sum[i][j] = s;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```